# SwiftUI, IF inside ForEach loop to display different text

Tags: arrays, swift, foreach, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I am having a hard time displaying certain text in a ForEach loop in SwiftUI.

I have an array that I iterate over with ForEach. The problem is, I need to have certain text displayed for whether or not a specific date is selected in a calendar.
For example:

```
ForEach(reminders) { reminder in 
    if(Calendar.current.isDate(reminder.beginDate, equalTo: selectedPassedDate) {
       HStack {
         Text("The Text for the specific day")
       } else {
         Text("The text for the unspecific day")
       }
    }
}
```

When the array has more than 2 elements, the text for the non-matching day is being displayed multiple times (since it is inside the foreach). This makes sense, but I am trying to figure out a way to only display ONE of the "unspecified day" text instead of many.

I have tried adding a simple bool to display the other text, but I cannot change the state of it without a button or something.. I need to do this totally programmatically. I've also moved the else statement outside of the loop but again the secondary text is being displayed in the current day selection.

What can I do to solve this issue? If I can programmatically set the bool while conforming to SwiftUIs view then I can solve this, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
class FirstTime: ObservableObject {
    var value = true
}

struct MyView: View {
    ...
    @State var firstTime = FirstTime()

    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(reminders) { reminder in
            HStack {
                if (Calendar.current.isDate(reminder.beginDate, equalTo: selectedPassedDate) {
                    Text("The Text for the specific day")
                } else {
                    if firstTime.value {
                        showTextOnce()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func showTextOnce() -> some View {
    firstTime.value = false
    return Text("The text for the unspecific day")
} 
}
```